# Boost Parallel Graph where to find the implementation of mpi process group synchronize

Tags: boost-graph, boost-graph-parallel

I have been trying to find the implementation for the "synchronize" function declared in boost\graph\distributed\mpi_process_group.hpp for serveral hours, but can't find it. Anyone can help?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's in the library sources, namely here: https://github.com/boostorg/graph_parallel/blob/develop/src/mpi_process_group.cpp#L762

You will usually not have the sources locally if you didn't compile the library yourself (e.g. installing from a package manager).